# iMovie- drawing?

Tags: video-editor, imovie

We have some movie, in which we would like to draw live on . So for example, you see an object in the movie, then a circle is being drawn around it , and a few small images jumps out of it.

Can this be done with iMovie ? something like picture in picture effect with the movie and some images ? or should we make the animation separately ?

I know iMovie has this frame by frame effect , but for this to work we would need to have many parts of a circle, then run them frame by frame to the movie- which seems problematic.

Then if we create the animation outside of a movie editor, it wouldn't be transparent - like around an object .

Whats the simplest way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36520/how-to-make-a-color-transparent-in-gimp) in the Graphic Design forum explains how to make an image background transparent in either of two ways.  If you have an animation you have captured (perhaps by screen-casting your drawing session into a series of images), you can use an image editing tool that can do batch processing, such as [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), to create the transparency type most appropriate for your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There ***is*** a way to draw in iMovie all you need is a video of a line drawing and then iMovie will do the rest! [image]

See if you put it on green/blue screen you can make the video transparent!
And it will still be a movie, I made my own movie on keynote! It is better if the movie has a different color background then the drawing because iMovie will just erase everything!